# Switch statement doesn't change value android

Tags: android, format, switch-statement

i have an imageview and a button , onclick i want to set different types of display (full screen, square, and an other vertical format), i have a switch statement but it doesn't work i don't know where i am doing wrong, please help me, maybe it is an easy question but still cant find solutions in google,

```
    private int format; 

    private void changeFormat(){
        switch (format) {
        case 0:
            format = 0;
            System.out.println("format is " + format);
            formatFullScreen();
            break;
        case 1:
            format = 1;
            System.out.println("format is " + format);
            formatSquare();
            break;

        case 2:
            format = 2;
            System.out.println("format is " + format);
            formatVertical();

            break;
        default:
            format = 0;
            System.out.println("format is " + format);
            formatFullScreen();
            break;
        }
    }
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.SetOnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        changeFormat();
        // in logcat it prints the format = 0 ; and it doesn't change everytime i click.
    }
```

Comment: you switch for the format and after selecting the case you set it. that makes no sense.
if you want to "change" the value do:
private void changeFormat(int value){format = value;}
if you want to do sth depending on the format value do:
private void doActionByFormat(){
switch(format):
case 0: //do
case ...
default: ...
}

Its always 0 because in the beginning it has no value. then when you click changeformat gets called. this switches to default and sets  it to 0.

Comment: Why does your code switch on `format` and also set the value of `format`? What did you want it to do with that variable and with calling the format methods?

Comment: @Jerry101, i want to switch format from 0 to 2, when format is 0 i want to call formatfullscreen(), when format is 1 i want to call an other method and so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a quick solution:

```
private int format = 0;

private void setFormat(int value){
  format = value;
}

private void doOperation(){
  switch(format){
    case 0: formatFullScreen(); break;
    case 1: formatSquare(); break;
    case 2: formatVertical(); break;
    default: formatFullScreen(); break;
  }
}

button.setOnClickListener(new View.SetOnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        incrementFormat();
        doOperation();
   }
}

private void incrementFormat(){
  format++;
  if(format > 2){
    format = 0;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you so much, it is working as i want. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`format` starts set to 0... and then this code runs:

```
case 0:
    format = 0;
    System.out.println("format is " + format);
    formatFullScreen();
    break;
```

and `format` stays at 0.

In each `case` statement, try setting `format` to the next value..

Comment: Yes, if the goal is to cycle between formats, it needs code to do that. Tip: Single-step through this method in the Android Studio debugger to learn how it operates vs. expected operation.